# How do I hide horizontal scroll bar and keep vertical scroll bar visible while still being able to scroll horizontally?

Tags: html, css, firefox, scrollbar, overflow

There are a lot of such questions but I haven't been able to find one which answers how to remove only the horizontal scroll bar while still being able to scroll horizontally:

I used the following code, but it removed both the horizontal and vertical scroll bars:

```
.section {
  overflow-y: auto;
  scrollbar-width: none; /*For firefox*/
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none; /*For remainder of the browsers*/
}
```

Comment: `display: none` will obviously affect both scrollbars. (Instead of setting the width I'd try setting the height for the horizontal scrollbar) There are various selectors, maybe [this article](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) helps

Comment: @SecretTimes No it doesn't say anything about keeping the vertical scroll bar visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.section {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.section::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```